# CSS Span Float Left

Tags: css, css-float

So I have a div and two spans:

```
<div class="A">
    <span class="B"></span>
    <span class="C"></span>
    <span class="clear"></span>
</div>
```

Assume that B and C has sufficient contents. The CSS snippet is:

```
.A { position: absolute; } /* I need this to be absolute */
.B, .C { float: left; }
.clear { clear: both; }
```

But I keep getting the layout of the right image, while I want it to be like layout of first image (refer to image below)
[image]

Please help me. And it would be better if you kindly explain a bit why do they happen and why is my code not working like I expected. How is float actually working. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>Your classes in the html are capitals but not in the CSS?</strike>

EDIT:

```css
.A { position: absolute; border: 1px solid blue; } 
.B, .C { float: left; border: 1px solid red; width: 100px; height: 20px; }
.C { height: 100px; }
.clear { clear: both; }
```

```html
<div class="A">
    <span class="B"></span>
    <span class="C"></span>
    <span class="clear"></span>
</div>
```

[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89v9U/2/)

Comment: oh sorry, it's a typo, but that's not the problem

Answer (score 2):

The class are case sensitive, "a" is not "A"!

change your HTML:

```
<div class="a">
    <span class="b"></span>
    <span class="c"></span>
    <span class="clear"></span>
</div>
```

also, the float works depending on the width. Give a width to both b and c divs...

Comment: You get +1 for case sensitivity, but -1 because `b` and `c` are `span`s, which by default are not `display: block`.  So, "I award you no points, and may God have mercy on your soul"

Comment: @saluce I didn't mention that, but it doesn't need it, thanks for the +1 that you didn't give me :)